# JavaScript creating a Date Object x seconds Ago?

Tags: javascript, date

Say I have a number x that can be anything (within reason). How would I create a new Date object that is x number of seconds ago? I have no idea about how to approach this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var seconds = 5;
var dateNow = new Date();
var date5SecondsAgo = new Date(dateNow.getTime() - seconds*1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var now = new Date();
var seconds = 15;
var before = new Date(now.getTime() - seconds*1000);
```

Comment: You should choose your answer and mark that thread as answered... It's the purpose of this platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the valueOf/getTime property to get the the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 and then there are 1,000 milliseconds in a seconds

```
var milliSecondPerSecond = 1000;
var myStartDate = new Date(myEndDateTime - numberOfSeconds * milliSecondPerSecond );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to do this, which I'm using in a real project. I used Date.now() and provided a second parameter to make it easy to test.

```
export const backDate = (secondsAgo: number, now: number = Date.now()): Date =>
  new Date(now - secondsAgo * 1000)
```

Here's a version without the typescript noise.

```
export const backDate = (secondsAgo, now = Date.now()) =>
  new Date(now - secondsAgo * 1000)
```

You can call it without the now parameter to get what you want.

```
const thirtySecondsAgo = backDate(30)
```